# Receiving the error "ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed." when running my application

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, drop-down-menu, textbox

I am trying to display some values in textboxes from a database by selecting a site ID from a drop down list. The drop down list is working perfectly and showing the site IDs that are stored in the database. While running this application it shows an error:

> Execute Reader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadOption();
        }
    }

 private void LoadOption()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"connectionString");
        using (con)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Site_ID FROM tbl_Survey1", con);
            adpt.Fill(dt);
            ddlSiteID.DataSource = dt;
            ddlSiteID.DataTextField = "Site_ID";
            ddlSiteID.DataValueField = "Site_ID";
            ddlSiteID.DataBind();
            ddlSiteID.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select ID--", ""));
        }
    }
 protected void ddlSiteID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"connectionString");
 string selectID = ddlSiteID.SelectedValue;
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Site_Name,Site_Address FROM tbl_Survey1 where Site_ID=@Site_ID", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Site_ID", selectID);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                rdr.Read();
                txtSiteName.Text = rdr.GetString(0);
                txtSiteAddress.Text=rdr.GetString(1);
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Source:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSiteID" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSiteID_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:TextBox ID="txtSiteName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:TextBox ID="txtSiteAddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: You should always use `using` not only sometimes. It also cannot hurt to do that on every object that implements `IDisposable` like also the `SqlDataAdapter`. But the main issue: you don't need to open the connection for `DataAdapter.Fill` but before you call `cmd.ExecuteReader()`.

Comment: You are not open connection in ddlSiteID_SelectedIndexChanged. In the future try to create Data Layer class and re use it ! I don't get it why this question is upvoted !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should open your connection by calling `con.Open()` before calling `ExecuteReader` in `ddlSiteID_SelectedIndexChanged` method. And don't forget to close it in the end.

This means your code may look like

```
protected void ddlSiteID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(var con = new SqlConnection(@"connectionString"))
    {
        string selectID = ddlSiteID.SelectedValue;
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Site_Name,Site_Address FROM tbl_Survey1 where Site_ID=@Site_ID", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Site_ID", selectID);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            con.Open();
            try
            {
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (rdr.HasRows)
                    {
                        rdr.Read();
                        txtSiteName.Text = rdr.GetString(0);
                        txtSiteAddress.Text=rdr.GetString(1);
                    }
               }
           }
           finally
           {
                con.Close();
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you write the code here. I am jus a begginer in programming. So can you help me.

Comment: @Vipin: He did. `con.Open()`. Right before the call to `ExecuteReader`.

Answer (score 4):

The error explains all. Your connection is closed when you call ExecuteReader. But I suppose that you are asking why?.

You think that, because you have already loaded the dropdown, then you could execute your reader without problems. But, unfortunately, the `SqlDataAdapter` has its own behavior when working with the connection.

From MSDN [SqlDataAdapter.Fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The Fill method retrieves rows from the data source using the SELECT
>   statement specified by an associated SelectCommand property. The
>   connection object associated with the SELECT statement must be valid,
>   but it does not need to be open. If the connection is closed before
>   Fill is called, it is opened to retrieve data, then closed. If the
>   connection is open before Fill is called, it remains open.

So you just need to open the connection in this way

```
protected void ddlSiteID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string selectID = ddlSiteID.SelectedValue;
   using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"connectionString"))
   using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Site_Name,Site_Address FROM tbl_Survey1 where Site_ID=@Site_ID", con))
   {
       con.Open();
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Site_ID", selectID);
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
          ....
       }
    }
 }
```

P.S. Remember to keep always your disposable objects like the connection, command and reader inside an Using block to be sure that they are closed and disposed correctly also in case of exceptions

Answer (score 3):

You're missing in the second method an explicit call to open your connection:

```
con.Open();
```

Also, you don't dispose of said connection -- be careful with that. Use `using`s for anything that implements `IDisposable`:

```
protected void ddlSiteID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"connectionString"))
    {
        con.Open();
        string selectID = ddlSiteID.SelectedValue;
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Site_Name,Site_Address FROM tbl_Survey1 where   Site_ID=@Site_ID", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Site_ID", selectID);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (rdr.HasRows)
                {
                    rdr.Read();
                    txtSiteName.Text = rdr.GetString(0);
                    txtSiteAddress.Text=rdr.GetString(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Andy: Thanks, I've correct my answer. And a +1 to you for getting there first!

Answer (score 0):

try this In `SelectedIndexChanged` event of DropDown.

`SqlCommand` requires Connection to be `open`

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"connectionString");
 string selectID = ddlSiteID.SelectedValue;
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Site_Name,Site_Address FROM tbl_Survey1 where Site_ID=@Site_ID", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Site_ID", selectID);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       con.open
{
 using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                rdr.Read();
                txtSiteName.Text = rdr.GetString(0);
                txtSiteAddress.Text=rdr.GetString(1);
            }
       }
}
    }
con.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your connection is open or not.

```
if (con != null && con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
   con.Open();
}
```